# codeigniter won't create a model and won't tell me why not

Tags: php, codeigniter

The controller code (including my tests) :

```
$inventory = $this->load->model('character/inventoryModel');

//include('C:\xampp\htdocs\proj\application\models\character\inventoryModel.php');
//$testObject = new InventoryModel(43);

//var_dump($inventory); die();
echo $inventory->checkInventory(25, 1, 43);
```

The model header and constructor:

```
class InventoryModel extends CI_Model
{
protected $who,
          $backpackCount,
          $equippedCount;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->backpackCount = 0;
    $this->equippedCount = 0;
    parent::__construct();
}
```

If I call from the test code the model returns fine, but from CI itself I get:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function on a
>   non-object

Dumping the instance returns null - the model isn't being instantiated from inside CI, but if I do a basic include and new it instantiates fine.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think I was trying to code while drunk.  And I wanted the facility for multiple instances of the same model, which clearly I can't do with vanilla CI.  Which is not ideal for what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->load->model('character/InventoryModel');
echo( $this->InventoryModel->checkInventory(25, 1, 43) );
```

From the CodeIgniter documentation:

*Once loaded, you will access your model functions using an object with the same name as your class*:

```
$this->load->model('Model_name');

$this->Model_name->function();
```

Here's the link: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html.

You should also note that you're using the wrong name of your model when loading it. The name should be "InventoryModel" instead of "inventoryModel", therefore the same name as the class itself.

And you're getting the fatal error message because the `model` method doesn't return anything, and it isn't supposed to at all, according to the documentation. Just load the model without the assignment and then use it through the name of your model class like shown above and in the documentation:

```
$this->InventoryModel->checkInventory(25, 1, 43)
```

Answer (score 0):

what I wanted can be achieved by passing a name parameter to the model constructor:

```
$this->load->model('myModel', 'myCustomModelName');
$value = $this->myCustomModelName->getValue();
```

simple as that.  Hopefully someone else can find this useful.